# How to modally present a view controller without dismissing the parent/first view controller

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm trying to animate up a `UICollectionViewController` over an original `UIViewController` with the original `UIViewController` blurred as background, however, every time the animation finishes, I can see clearly through the blurred view that the original view controller is dismissed, what do I do to avoid the first `UIViewController` being dismissed?

**Code in the first view controller to present the second:**

```
let VC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopoverCollectionVC") as! PopoverCollectionVC
VC.setDataSource(with: .calcDPSItems)
VC.collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
VC.transitioningDelegate = self
self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Code in the animator object for custom animation:**

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
    let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)!
    let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)!

    if presenting {
        // configure blur
        effectView.frame = fromView.bounds
        containerView.addSubview(effectView)
        // configure collection view
        toView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: fromView.frame.height, width: fromView.frame.width, height: fromView.frame.height / 2)
        containerView.addSubview(toView)

        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: .calculationModeCubic, animations: {

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.6) {
                toView.center.y = fromView.center.y
            }

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.1, relativeDuration: 1) {
                self.effectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
            }

        }) { _ in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        }
    } else {

        ...
    }
```

Comment: try `VC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext` before `self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: @Aladin it crashed on the line: let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)!, saying the value is nil

Comment: `// Get the from view from The ViewController because there is a bug in iOS when using some modalPresentationStyle values that causes the viewForKey to returm nil for UITransitionContextFromViewKey
        // www.splinter.com.au/2015/04/17/ios8-view-controller-transitioning-bug/
        let fromVC  = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)
        let fromView  = fromVC?.view`

Comment: @Aladin thanks! That's how my problem was solved

Comment: Glad it helped :) , I have posted an answer for future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that the modal presentation style will be over the current context :

```
VC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

Then to get the the presented view you need

```
// Get the from view from The ViewController because there is a bug in iOS when 
// using some modalPresentationStyle values 
// that causes the viewForKey to returm nil for UITransitionContextFromViewKey 
// www.splinter.com.au/2015/04/17/ios8-view-controller-transiti‌​oning-bug/ 

let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) 
let fromView = fromVC?.view
```

Answer (score 0):

You should instead take a snapshot of the previous view, then blur than and use it as a background on the new VC.

```
 let oldView = view_to_copy.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
```

Then blur this, and add as a subview to your collectionView controller.

EDIT:

Just to add if you are using the VC inside something like UITabbar or UINavigationController you may need to snapshot that view to ensure all the UI is inside the snapshot.